# VS 2010 Debugging - Where's the visualizers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

During debugging I was trying to look at a StringBuilder's contents in order to visualize it. I work with a lot of HTML and I would like to be able to view the content in HTML mode like it was possible in VS 2008.

As you can see in the image attached, in 2008 I could very easily get the html mode right in the debugger on the line I wanted. ***In 2010, I have to call the ToString() method in order to get the same ability.***

How can I get the abilities of 2008 back in 2010?

[image: VS 2010 compared to VS 2008]

Thank you.

Comment: That is a bummer. I thought there'd be a Non-Public or Static member that had the actual string, but no dice. I'd add a feature request to MS connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated Seth Richards' VS2010 StringBuilder Visualizer solution so that HTML content that may exist in the StringBuilder object will be rendered. [You can download the solution here](http://albao.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/stringbuildervisualizer_browserview.xls) *(rename the .xls extension to .zip)*- and/or [go here for more information](http://albao.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/html-visualizer-for-stringbuilder-type-in-visual-studio-2010/) on what changes I made to Seth's solution.

Note: The update I made is not as extensive as the default debugger visualizer either. However it, at least, will render your HTML instead of just showing the raw string.

Answer (score 1):

[S H Richards](http://blog.shrichards.com/index.php/visualizing-a-stringbuilder/) made a custom Visualizer for the StringBuilder type.

I haven't tried it myself, so I cannot vouch for whether or not it works. However, you can download his [StringBuilderVisualizer Solution here](http://files.shrichards.com/Visualizers/StringBuilderVisualizer.zip) and test it yourself.

If you try it out, please share your results with us ;)

Comment: Tried it but its not as extensive as the default debugger visualizer. I couldn't find a way to call that form myself. Even tried to change the display myself to just Length: [assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"\{{Length}}", Target = typeof(System.Text.StringBuilder))] but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Visualizer for `String`, `StringBuilder` and `DataTable` objects on sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualizer/

The visualizer dialogs open non-modally, allowing the code to be edited and recompiled without having to close the windows.

[image: StringBuilder Visualizer]